# Is it possible to combine two different database utility like Teradata's Fast export to Greenplum's GPloader?

Tags: teradata, greenplum, fastexport

Usually, I use a JDBC connection with some ETL tool to move data from one database(i.e Teradata) to another database(i.e Greenplum).

However, both of these databases comes with inbuilt utilities which can load/export huge amounts of data very fast, far faster than JDBC!. But the downside as far as I am aware of is that it can do so only to/from a file.

So, if I want to use them I have to Follow a process like-

Teradata ---(Fast Export)---> File ---(Gploader)---> Greenplum

I am wondering if it is possible to skip the File part and Combine the two utilities.

Teradata ---(FastExport & Gploader)--> Greenplum.

That way I can transfer huge amounts of data very quickly!

Comment: FastExport (and the newer & recommended TPT Export) can export to a Named Pipe, don't know if GPloader supports reading from a pipe

Comment: A named pipe gives you a single input channel. No need to use gpload. You can just pipe this into COPY.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you most certainly can.  Greenplum supports all kinds of external tables.  One solution is to use an External Table that executes a command.  That command can be a Java program that connects to Teradata to get data and uses the FastExport option.

I wrote the tool "gplink" to do just this.  It automates the creation of Greenplum External Tables for JDBC sources.

Github:
https://github.com/pivotalguru/gplink

Teradata connection example:
https://github.com/pivotalguru/gplink/blob/master/connections/teradata.properties

And my blog:
http://www.pivotalguru.com/?page_id=982